# How to pass an argument from grunt task to karma-runner

Tags: gruntjs, karma-runner

I am using grunt-karma to launch the unit test suite.  I need to lookup a value from a grunt task, and then pass the value to karma for use in the tests.

Grunt task doing a lookup:

```
  grunt.registerMultiTask('lookup', 'Lookup value', function() {
        var value = 5; // just hard code here for now
```

I need to then pass value to the grunt-karma task as defined:

```
        karma: {
          options: {
            configFile: 'karma.conf.js'
          },
```

Can I use grunt.config to pass value to karma-runner?

```
var value = 5; //just hardcode here for now
...
grunt.config("karma.customParam",value);
```

And then how could I retrieve the value from the test specs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know this answer is too late. But I hope it helps someone.

```
karma: {
  options: {
    configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
    client: {
      args: ['test']
    }
  },
```

In tests spec, you can retrieve the values like below

```
window.__karma__.config.args[0]  // 'test'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Note: It might be tempting to add client:args into the configFile itself however this doesn't work. The client:args has to be in Gruntfile when using grunt.